# Angular Scope not updating

Tags: angularjs

I'm using facebook login am having trouble properly setting `$scope.user`. It is not being set automatically on the callback but only once I click something else on the page. I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing but could use some help.

My HTML

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" 
    role="navigation" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
      <p class="navbar-text pull-right"> 
        {{ user.name }} 
      </p> 
      <button 
        class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right" 
        ng-hide="user"
        ng-click="login()">Log In With Facebook
      </button>
  </nav>
```

HomeCtrl:

```
 .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user;

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    $scope.login = function() {
      FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $scope.user = response;
          });
        } 
      }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'} );
    }
  })
```

If I run `console.log($scope.user)` after I set it to the response, it seems as though `$scope.user` is being set, however, it's not reflected in the HTML until after another element is clicked.

Comment: This is one of the numerous `$scope.$apply()` related question i guess?

Comment: @PSL, yes. Leave an answer and I'll accept, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The facebook login callback is not executed by angular. So angular doesn't have any way to know that it modified the scope, and that it has to reevaluate the expressions used in the HTML page.

You thus need to tell angular that something has changed in the scope:

```
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.user = response;
        });
      });
```